# Watir can't click on an element but can on irb

Tags: automated-testing, xpath, watir

I have this command:

```
@browser.element(:xpath => "/html/body/app/pages/div/div/div/div[3]/mi-perfil/div/div[3]/datos-personales/div/div[1]/span[2]").click
```

There is no problem with the direction of the Xpath, thats why i don't add the HTML code which is gigantic.

**The Problem**

When i run a scenario that run this command, I get :

> unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point
>   (431, 8). Other element would receive the click: ...

**BUT** when i get into the IRB running each command, the click is done without problem.

I'm doing a click there because that span contains a button, like this:

```
<span> 
<button class="btn btn-blue btn-less-rounded btn-s" type="button">Guardar</button> 
</span>
```

*If I add `/button` to the Xpath i get the same Error

*If I use `.exists?` gives =>true

*If I use `.visible?` gives =>true

*If I use `.text` gives =>Guardar

Comment: Really `IRB` or is that `rails console`. just curious

Comment: I don't have Rails installed in this PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to click on it.
What happened is that the button wasn't directly visible when it did the click so the error pop up. And with watir alone was extremely dificult but I manage to scroll easier with

```
gem install watir-scroll
```

Then you add to the step file:

```
require 'watir-scroll'
```

And in the code before the click I put this:

```
@browser.element(blabla).scroll.to :center
```

With this i make sure the button is in the visible part of the Browser.

Thanks for the hints ;)

Answer (score 0):

Things I would try:

- Try using find first to see if it scroll the item into view
- Try using waits to see if it is a timing issue (start with a sleep to investigate, switch to explicit element wait if found).
- Try resizing the windowe

Comment: I did as you suggested and this is what i got: _Try using find first_ = I did scroll to the element and still got the same problem. _Try using waits_ = I did wait and continued the flow since it finds it. _Try resizing the window_ = I try to maximize and stuff with the window and still got the same problem.